# Video - AVI Plugin for Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.4, extensions

Can someone let me know if there is a plugin / application that will let me upload videos to site. And when users want to access the video they will prompted for login and password

Cheers

Carlton

Answer (score 1):

The best place to look for extensions is the [JED (Joomla! Extension Directory)](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension?searchall=&filter%5Btags%5D%5B%5D=&filter%5Bcore_catid%5D=246&filter%5Bincludes%5D=&filter%5Bversions%5D=&filter%5Btype%5D=&filter%5Bhasdemo%5D=&order=num_reviews&filter%5Bnewupdated%5D=&filter%5Bscore%5D=&filter%5Bfavourites%5D=&dir=DESC&limitstart=0&controller=filter&view=extension&layout=list&Itemid=145&clearorders=0&clearfilters=1).

---

**Option 1:**

[AllVideos](http://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/free/allvideos) is by far the most popular video player extension available for Joomla! since it is a very lightweight plugin (no components or modules).

What I would do is create a category of articles that is restricted to registered users. Then, create articles inside that category with the videos embedded.

---

**Option 2:**

If you want an all-inclusive component that would keep management of the videos more like YouTube or Vimeo, you could check out [All Share Video](http://allvideoshare.mrvinoth.com/) (free) or [HD Video Share](https://www.apptha.com/category/extension/joomla/hd-video-share) (premium).

Answer (score 1):

I have recommend [Joomla videoplayer](http://yendifplayer.com/products-listing/joomla-video-share.html) extension for joomla. excellent free support,live chat, forum and more features. Easily understandable coding structure, easy to change as own..